# Combining Multiple Point Clouds

Tags: computer-vision, point-cloud

I have a car with 8 lidars, each with a field of view of 60 degrees. My car looks like this [image]

How can I merge all the lidar readings into 1 point cloud?

Comment: So, what exactly are your point clouds as data? A list of (range, azimuth, elevation) tuples, relative to the lidar sensor position, I assume?

Comment: Yes the lidar is stored in this way

Comment: So, all you need to do is transform these coordinates to a common coordinate system through rotation and translation?